# How should one start on creating a sbt plugin?

Tags: plugins, sbt, scala-2.9

I want to create a sbt plugin for Scala project.

Please any one suggest me how we start?

I referred [Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Extending/Plugins.html) documentation but unable to understand steps.

Comment: Please be more specific with what you have problems. There are a lot of SBT plugins out there: https://github.com/search?q=sbt+plugin

Answer (score 5):

The first step in becoming a sbt plugin author is understanding sbt build definition. The best resource for it is [Getting Started guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Welcome.html). For plugins, it's essential that you understand the concept of scoping. Some of my blog posts like [an unofficial guide to sbt 0.10 v2.0](http://eed3si9n.com/sbt-010-guide) and [traveling through the 4th dimension with sbt 0.13](http://eed3si9n.com/4th-dimension-with-sbt-013) discuss the topic.

Next, try reading the source code for existing plugins:

- [sbt/sbt-appengine](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-appengine/blob/8a0dd5b8dd9e516f9c2f4b9d0725ca14d3b2ca12/src/main/scala/AppenginePlugin.scala)

  - `sbt-appengine` adds defines `appengineSettings`, which the build user can include in his or her build definition to add `appengineDeploy` and other appengine related tasks.
- [sbt/sbt-man](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-man/blob/240e4afcc5a1f87fbba171ab93406cc79ced46e0/src/main/scala/sbtman/Plugin.scala)

  - `sbt-man` on the other hand overrides `settings` and adds `man` command.

These are roughly two patterns for plugins. Once you understand them fully, try making your own plugin.

Another source of inspiration is the source for sbt itself. Whenever I'm writing a plugin, I'd consult [Defaults.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/5275dcab4b9512f941daceda9fa3d843899612d1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala) to see how sbt implements a particular task that I'm interested in. Once you're comfortable, you should also read [Plugins Best Practices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html) too.